# Find the Laurent series for $p(4/z)$

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

> Find the Laurent series for $p(4/z)$ given that $p(z)=(z-3)^3$

My attempt: if the Taylor series for $p(z)$ looks like

$$\frac{-27}{0!}+ \frac{27z}{1!}-\frac{18z^2}{2!}+ \frac{6z^3}{3!}+0+0+0...$$

Then the Laurent series is probably the same thing but with a $4$ over the numerator. But then I'm confused about the point we expand about.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to find Taylor series, in this case the series is Laourent also because the series includes terms of negative degree.

$$p(z)=-27+27z-9z^2+z^3=\sum_{n=0}^{3}z^n(-3)^{3-n}\binom {3}{n}\\
p(4/z)=\frac{64}{z^3}-\frac{144}{z^2}+\frac{108}{z}-27$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $p(z)=(z-3)^3$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
p(4/z)&=\frac{(4-3z)^3}{z^3}\\\\
&=\frac{-27z^3+108z^2-144z+64}{z^3}\\\\
&=-27+108\frac1z-144\frac1{z^2}+64\frac1{z^3}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Oh I was still giving your answer some thought. No worries. I'm working on how you got to line 2. Could you help me understand Laurent series more? The only relationship to the Taylor series that I've found is that the Laurent series can have negative terms, but that's so vague...also, Taylor series requires a point to expand about. This makes sense because we are finding a substitute function that can ''hug'' the function around that point. So then what would the Laurent series look like visually? What is it doing/representing?

Comment: For Line 2, we substitute $4/z$ for $z$ into the expression given for $p(z)$.  To answer your general questions on Laurent series, [see this Wikipedia articel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) for a good primer on Laurent series.